# How to use Python tkSimpleDialog.askstring

Tags: python, user-input, tkinter

I want to use the response from an askstring prompt to set a variable. Unfortunately,
I have the dilemma that I'm trapped in the loop asking the question or the window refuses to draw because the variable (urltoopen) has no value. 
The code as it stands:

```
urltoopen = tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Address', 'Where do we get the pictures from?')
usock = urllib2.urlopen(urltoopen)
data = usock.read()    
usock.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tkSimpleDialog.askstring](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x1164-data-entry.htm) returns `None` if the user clicks Cancel or closes the window (instead of clicking Ok or using the Enter key); you should check for that (what do you want to do if the user chooses to cancel? surely not call `urlopen` anyway...).

Apart from that, you're using the function correctly; I imagine that by "has no value" you mean `is None`, right?

Comment: The window is not opening. Instead of starting the program returns <code>'NoneType' object has no attribute 'winfo_viewable'</code>. Should it be set up as an 'if' 'else' type situation as with some other tkSimple stuff? Could I see an example of tkSimpleDialog setting a string variable with the response it receives and then allowing the program to continue (the dialog ends)?

Comment: Oops. I think I got it working. Thank you for the input. Now, I'll need to clear up the blank tkinter widget that appears and enable copy and paste.

Comment: I found that tkSimpleDialog.askstring did not return None. It returned boolean true or false. When I wrote : if  tkSimpleDialog.askstring is None, this clause was ALWAYS executed, even if pressed cancel on the dialog. Using Python 2.7 on windows 10.

Comment: The link is 404. Which package do I need for this? I have installed `ttkSimpleDialog` (note the double t) but it does not have `askstring()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
root = Tk()   


try:
        urltoopen = tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Ask Address', 'Where do we get the pictures from?')
        usock = urllib2.urlopen(urltoopen)                                                       
        data = usock.read()                                                                      
        usock.close()                                                                            
        a = data                                                                                 
except:                                                                                          
        sys.exit()
```

works fine. But it does need error handling (as mentioned by Alex).